# HTML does not show "<" symbol

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I have a `TextField` in HTML with the value

```
<b> 1 > 0 and x <= 5 </b>
```

converting it to PDF with iReport it shows

```
<b> 1 > 0 and X = 5 </b>
```

so the "<" symbol is missing, what might be the problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: try it with < = &lt; and > = &gt; don't use the symbols

Comment: did my first comment work? If so accept an answer to close the question.

Comment: thanks, this solution works well, but why the ">" if it shows?

Comment: That's random, you were lucky that it works. It may change with a new code. If it worked accept my answer to close the question :) There's no rule if the symbol is shown or not, use always the entity name, much better in case of compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the symbols. Use the correct entity name instead. Those symbols are reserved for the HTML code and not for the "normal" use.

```
< = &lt;
```

and

```
> = &gt;
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) you will find these entity names.